# How to make sidebar appear after content on mobile even if there are full-width blocks in content?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I tried wrapping fixed-width-content and sidebar in a shared container but for mobile could only think of a solution where you place sidebar after content and before full-width-content. Latter is undesirable.

[Desirable result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJE3e.jpg)

[The codepen I am trying to get working](https://codepen.io/edele/pen/dRQVgK)

```
<div class="everything">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar should be the last one on mobile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width-container">full-width-container</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could just copy and paste the sidebar code above the footer (or whatever you want it) and use a media query to change it&#39;s display property on mobile while hiding the other sidebar seen on desktop screens. Although this really isn't an ideal way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible solutions to this design challenge, but one that sticks out is to use flexbox. Here is a great guide to flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but the specific property that will be advantageous for you will be the **order** property.

You can put all the items in a flex container, and each piece which you have shown in your mock will be flex-items (children of the flex container). You will then set the order property of the flex-items on desktop normally.

```
flex-item1 { order: 1; }
flex-item-sidebar { order: 2; }
flex-item3 { order: 3; }
flex-item4 { order: 4; }
```

This isn't super necessary as flex items are laid out in the source order. However, for your mobile CSS, you will set the order like this:

```
flex-item1 { order: 1; }
flex-item-sidebar { order: 3; } // note this change
flex-item3 { order: 2; }
flex-item4 { order: 4; }
```

The order property controls the order in which they appear in the flex container and thus you can change the order with CSS and for different screen sizes using min and max widths!

In the link I provided, there are also some great layout examples that you could probably grab and play around with them to meet your needs (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-examples).

EDIT: Here is something I did quickly in codepen that should work for you. Resize the screen to see it in action. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZQWXw#anon-login

Comment: But content and sidebar should be in a fixed width container on desktop version. I am trying to achieve a proper result here: https://codepen.io/edele/pen/dRQVgK

Comment: Ah that makes it more difficult if you want the top contents to be fixed on the page on desktop. In this case then flexbox will not work because when you make an item fixed you are taking it out of the normal flow of the DOM elements.

What you could do is make it position: fixed on desktop (with no flexbox styling) and then for mobile style remove the fixed position and add all the flex styling that I have detailed in my answer.